# JS smooth setTimeout class removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have some hidden rows inside a table and I would like to remove a class after expanding the table. But it creates a flickering or jumpy effect. Can I prevent that? I would like to have the effect without the class removal JS. To be more specific I'm trying to remove the

> padding: 0 !important;

after expanding the table.

JS to remove the class:

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function(event) {
    target_data = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
    classes = target_data.attr("class").split(/\s+/);
    id = target_data.attr("data-target").replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    console.log(classes);
    if (classes.includes('collapsed')) {
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].classList.add("hiddenRow");
            for (j = 0; j < elements[i].cells.length; j++){
            elements[i].cells[j].classList.add("hiddenRow");
            };
        }
    } else {
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
        console.log(elements);
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("hiddenRow");
            for (j = 0; j < elements[i].cells.length; j++){
            elements[i].cells[j].classList.remove("hiddenRow");
            };
        }
    };
    }, 200);
})
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e6L8ndhk/1/

Comment: I see multiple rows with `hiddenRow` class. Try making a single row with `hiddenRow` class per entry and put the content into a new table inside that row.

Comment: Seems like table inside a tr isn't a thing